# Why does Chrome load an image of my page after the page has finished loading?

Tags: php, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This is such a bizarre thing that even just typing in the title makes me question my own sanity.  Anyway, I'm trying to figure out why my reports are taking so long to load and I've discovered that Chrome is loading an image of my page, after the page has finished loading.  But don't take my word for it, check this screenshot from dev tools.

[image]

You can see that there are two instances of report.test.php being loaded.  The first one is a document and the second one is an img.  (You can tell by the icon and also by filtering the list on those two types).

So in this example the report is small and loads about 15 rows of data and renders them in an HTML table.  This is done after 710 ms (in this example) and it all looks good except that the favicon in the browser tab keeps spinning for another 808 ms while that img loads.  Not a huge deal on a small report like this one but if you load a lot more data that takes, for example, 6 seconds to load, then this second image also takes an additional 6 seconds to load for a total of 12 and that's a big deal.

Now as I said, when the document is finished loading I can see that the HTML has finished rendering so I can essentially use the report and ignore the spinning favicon, but this causes problems if I try to load another report, in another tab, while that favicon is still spinning.  It gets jammed up and basically brings everything to a grinding halt and it's all bad.  Bottom line, I need to stop this from happening.

So what is this img version of my report?  Why is it there and can I prevent it?

Comment: Look for something like `<img src="">`. That will try to use the page as the source of an image.

Comment: There are three img tags, so I commented them all out, but it's still doing it.  :-(

Comment: @Barmar turns out chrome was generating its own image because I set the background image to a blank string in my body style.  So you were right and set me on the right track, though I had no img tags I guess it does the same for css.

Comment: Yeah, anything that displays an image. I just wasn't thinking broad enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out chrome was generating its own image because I told it to use a blank background image in my body style.

**Background**

I had added `background:url('')` to the body tag of the reports page.

```
<body style="background:url('')">
```

I did this because the stylesheet I was using at the time added a background image, which I wanted for every other page in my app but not the reports page, so this was my way of overriding the style sheet.

**Solution**

Anyway, apparently when you submit a blank string as a background image chrome then generates its own image and it does so by making an image of the entire page, and the more HTML on the page the longer it takes to generate this image.

The solution is to not pass in a blank string to background:url.

Comment: Any blank URL is equivalent to the page URL.

Comment: You can use `background-image: none` to get rid of the background.

Comment: @Barmar I learned something new today.  :)